# Removing sharing account folder from workgroup network sharing in windows 7

Tags: network-shares, workgroup

I have enabled network sharing for my printer and public folder in my workgroup network, which is required for me to share. But my account folder is also got shared over the same workgroup network, which I don't want to share. I have tried a lot of google search and search almost every part of the control panel related to ntework sharing, but still I am not able to remove my my account folder from network share.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the sharing wizard.

Go to Control Panel -> Folder Options. In the new window, open the second tab called View. Scroll down (near the bottom) to "Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)" and uncheck.